# FFmpeg audio conversion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have been using FFMPEG for some time for audio file conversions.  I just downloaded the newest version and the command below:

```
ffmpeg -i x.flac -ab 128k x.mp3
```

no longer produces a 128k file.
It produces a 48k file no matter what the -ab command requests.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#SEC3)

> `-ab bitrate'
>   Set the audio bitrate in bit/s (default = 64k).

So this is the bitrate, which means that per second by default 64k bits are used for storing sound information. So only a one second file would return a 128k file.

If I misunderstood your question and you mean that the bitrate is 48k instead of 128k then double check if ffmpeg is not using variable bit rate. If this is not the case I suggest you submit a [bug report](http://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html).

Comment: Figured it out.  It seems that the program I was using (Goldwave4.0) to report the bit rate does not report properly with the newer encoding. Goldwave 5.0 does report properly.